# using string to pass filename to fstream

Tags: c++, string, fstream

I am using the following method to read a txt file

```
modelStream.open("file.txt", ios::in);
if (modelStream.fail())
    exit(1);
model = new Model(modelStream);
```

but i want to know how i can pass in a string as a parameter

```
string STRING;
modelStream.open(STRING, ios::in);
if (modelStream.fail())
    exit(1);
model = new Model(modelStream);
```

does anyone know if this is possible and if it is how would I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For legacy reasons, *iostreams* in C++03 expects a C-style, null-terminated string as argument and doesn't understand `std::string`. Fortunately, `std::string` can produce a C-style, null-terminated string, with the function `std::string::c_str()`:

```
modelStream.open(STRING.c_str(), ios::in);
```

This was actually "fixed" in C++11, so if you were using it your original code would be functional.

Also, an all-caps variable name is not recommended; neither is a variable called "string". Make the name describe the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `c_str ()` method of `std::string`

`modelStream.open(STRING.c_str (), ios::in);`

Answer (score 0):

the standard streams doesn't accept a standard string, only c-string! So pass the string using c_str():

```
modelStream.open(STRING.c_str(), ios::in);
```